# Is js executed after form synchronized submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

my code is as following:

```
form.submit();//synchronized submit, not asynchronous,the form is not a html form but created by javascript
some codes here;//Is this line executed, or it sometimes executed sometimes not
```

I have some statistics code(send a http request to a server) in 2rd line and really get some data. Because there is a big gap between the statistic data and expected, I doubt 2rd line is always executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what the form does on submit:

- If the form submits normally, then the code *may* run. Normal form submission redirects the browser to the url defined in the action attribute. The code may run but the page is already preparing to leave thus you may not see what the code after `form.submit()` does.
- If the form submits and is caught by JavaScript (maybe by an event handler), then the code after `form.submit()` *could* run but depends on what that event handler does. If the handler does not prevent normal form submission, then the situation is the same as the first. If the handler prevents normal form submission, then it can run.

I suggest you build a handler for that form that prevents normal form submission using techniques like `return false` and/or `event.preventDefault()` and also, run the code in there as well.

Comment: Basically this.  If you click on a link or submit a form, it will fire whatever events are tied to that event, and then it will start redirecting the browser.  As soon as the browser starts redirecting, any open connections (async connections, or things like images which still haven't downloaded) get cancelled -- even if it takes a while for the server to come back with the next page -- the code afterward, if it has *any* image/script/link/etc calls to send data, will most-usually be cancelled on "onunload()".  So if you're relying on async/external data, the trick is to postpone form.submit()

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i am still not sure