# jQuery - Proper way of disabling buttons on submit

Tags: jquery

My question is what's the best approach to implement disabing of buttons on page with jQuery after any of the buttons for form submit is clicked.
Something similar is available here [Is js executed after form synchronized submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944703/is-js-executed-after-form-synchronized-submit) where it's stated that my code in question (1.) "may" run.
All code is on document ready.

1. I've seen code like that in our project, but is it really guaranteed that the last line - button("disable") is invoked?

   ```
   $("#saveButton").on("click", function () {
       $("#myForm").submit();
       $("#saveButton").button("disable");
   });
   ```
2. Alternative would be this (it could be problematic, if button would get disabled, but he last line could also fail, so it doesn't really "feel good".

   ```
   $("#saveButton").on("click", function () {
       $("#saveButton").button("disable");
       $("#myForm").submit();
   });
   ```
3. This is probably the best approach, right? Can there be any "gotchas"?

   ```
   $("#myForm").submit(function () {
       $("#saveButton").button("disable");
       // disable also all the elements that can do a submit
       return true;
   });
   ```

Comment: use bind() and unbind() functions

Comment: 2 doesn't look like it'd pose any problems to me. But 3 seems the best solution.

Comment: What do you think about 1.?

Comment: @theberserker It will most likely not work. In most cases this will refresh your page (thus reloading everything) or send you to another page (if the action of your form links to another page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit is nearly the best approach, the "One" approach will give you only one chance, if your submit fails or not validates you are stucked

```
$('#myForm').on('submit',function () {
    $('#saveButton').button('disable');
    // disable also all the elements that can do a submit

    //Validate
    if (validate)
        return true;
    else  {
         //cancels submit
         $('#saveButton').button('enable');
         return false;
    }
});
```